# Hints regarding the use of ANTLR v3 generated files in Flash Builder 4.5.1

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, antlr, antlrworks

According to these [instructions](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3ActionScriptTarget), I'm trying to use ANTLR generated *.as files in a current Flash Builder 4.5.1 project.

Therefore, I added this [ANTLR's Actionscript runtime](http://antlr.org/download/ActionScript/antlr3.swc) to my project - without problems.

I compiled lexer/parser specs using [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html) without problems too.

I added the language option to the source *.g file to make ANTLR generate Actionscript sources:

```
options {
    backtrack = true; 
    memoize = true;
    k=2;
    output = AST;
    language=ActionScript;        // Added this
    ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}
```

Unfortunately, the ANTLR/ANTLRworks generated Actionscript code is buggy:

Catch statements read like this `catch (RecognitionException re)`, but should read like this:  `catch ( re:RecognitionException )`.

Furthermore, Flash Builder complains about the use of Array here:

```
public override function get tokenNames():Array { return PhpParser.tokenNames; }
```

Could anybody confirm these problems and probably provide hints how to solve them?

**UPDATE-1**

A quick look at the sources of ANTLR v3.3 revealed this template code [line 142 @ ActionScript.stg]:

```
catch ( re:RecognitionException )
```

Thus, the current 3.3 branch seems to know the correct syntax.

Unfortunately, the current ANTLRworks 1.4.2 - which includes the 3.3 branch - fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terence Parr, the project lead of ANTLR just confirmed, that ANTLRworks needs a new compile. Thanks for great support!

Comment: I tried to compile the *.g file using antlr-3.3-complete.jar. Since the output doesn't compile too, the problem seems to be in fact inside of the base ANTLR system, not ANTLRworks. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Last comment: All in all, the generated AS code doesn't seem to match the above mentioned ANTLR runtime library. Found more problem. The runtime defines a getter line() of ChartStream, the generated AS code calls it wrong, etc. Hm...