# Strategies for simplifying math expressions

Tags: algorithm, math, simplify

I have a well-formed tree that represents a mathematical expression.  For example, given the string: `"1+2-3*4/5"`, this gets parsed into:

```
subtract(add(1,2),divide(multiply(3,4),5))
```

Which is expressed as this tree:

[image: "1+2-3*4/5"]

What I'd like to be able to do is take this tree and reduce it as much as possible.  In the case above, this is pretty simple, because all of the numbers are constants.  However, things start to get trickier once I allow for unknowns (denoted with a `$` followed by an identifier):

`"3*$a/$a"` becomes `divide(multiply(3,$a), $a)`

This should simplify to `3`, since the `$a` terms should cancel each other out.  The question is, "how do I go about recognizing this in a generic manner?"  How do I recognize that `min(3, sin($x))` is always going to be `sin($x)`?  How do I recognize that `sqrt(pow($a, 2))` is `abs($a)`?  How do I recognize that `nthroot(pow(42, $a), $a)` (the a<sup>th</sup> root of 42 to the a<sup>th</sup> power) is `42`?

I realize this question is pretty broad, but I've been beating my head against this for a while and haven't come up with anything satisfactory enough.

Comment: And what about `sqrt(pow(-3, 2))`?

Comment: @Howard that evaluates to `3`, and is an example of why I haven't been able to think of a good answer yet (edited question to reflect that). :)

Comment: Also see my answer. You'll have to define lots of rule which transformations are allowed and which aren't.

Comment: `3a/a` is not the same as `3` because `3a/a` is undefined when `a=0`.

Comment: @NickJohnson Interesting hint! Doesn't 3*a/a equal 3 even when a = 0, since lim( a->0|left, 3*a/a ) = 3 and lim( a->0|right, 3*a/a ) = 3?

Comment: @StefanPantke No, because x/0 is undefined for all x. A function (like this one) can have a point discontinuity, even if the limits are consistent from either direction.

Comment: Thx! Just thought things changed - since certain sub-atomic elements these days seem to fly faster than light speed ;-)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You probably want to implement a [term rewriting system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting). Regarding the underlying math, have a look at [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting).

**Structure of a term rewrite module**

Since I implemented a solution recently...

- First, prepare a class CExpression, which models the structure of your expression.
- Implement `CRule`, which contains a pattern and a replacement. Use special symbols as pattern variables, which need to get bound during pattern matching and replaced in the replacement expression.
- Then, implement a class `CRule`. It's main method `applyRule(CExpression, CRule)` tries to match the rule against any applicable subexpression of expression. In case it matches, return the result.
- Finaly, implement a class `CRuleSet`, which is simply a set of CRule objects. The main method `reduce(CExpression)` applies the set of rules as long as no more rules can be applied and then returns the reduced expression.
- Additionally, you need a class `CBindingEnvironment`, which maps already matched symbols to the matched values.

**Try to rewrite expression to a normal form**

Don't forget, that this approach works to a certain point, but is likely to be non complete. This is due to the fact, that all of the following rules perform local term rewrites.

To make this local rewrite logic stronger, one should try to transform expressions into something I'd call a normal form. This is my approach:

- If a term contains literal values, try to move the term as far to the right as possible.
- Eventually, this literal value may appear rightmost and can be evaluated as part of a fully literal expression.

**When to evaluate fully literal expression**

An interesting question is when to evaluate fully literal expression. Suppose you have an expression

```
   x * ( 1 / 3 )
```

which would reduce to

```
   x * 0.333333333333333333
```

Now suppose x gets replaced by 3. This would yield something like

```
   0.999999999999999999999999
```

Thus eager evaluation returns a slightly incorrect value.

At the other side, if you keep ( 1 / 3 ) and first replace x by 3

```
   3 * ( 1 / 3 )
```

a rewrite rule would give

```
   1
```

Thus, it might be useful to evaluate fully literal expression late.

**Examples of rewrite rules**

Here is how my rules appear inside the application: The _1, _2, ... symbols match any subexpression:

```
addRule( new TARuleFromString( '0+_1',   // left hand side  :: pattern
                               '_1'      // right hand side :: replacement
                             ) 
       );
```

or a bit more complicated

```
addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_1+_2*_1', 
                               '(1+_2)*_1' 
                             ) 
       );
```

Certain special symbols only match special subexpressions. E.g. _Literal1, _Literal2, ... match only literal values:

```
addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'exp(_Literal1) * exp(_Literal2 )', 
                               'exp( _Literal1 + _Literal2 )' 
                             ) 
       );
```

This rule moves non-literal expression to the left:

```
addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal*_NonLiteral', 
                               '_NonLiteral*_Literal' 
                             ) 
       );
```

Any name, that begins with a '_', is a pattern variable. While the system matches a rule, it keeps a stack of assignments of already matched symbols.

Finally, don't forget that rules may yield non terminating replacement sequences.
Thus while reducing expression, make the process remember, which intermediate expressions have already been reached before.

In my implementation, I don't save intermediate expressions directly. I keep an array of MD5() hashes of intermediate expression.

**A set of rules as a starting point**

Here's a set of rules to get started:

```
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '0+_1', '_1' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal2=0-_1', '_1=0-_Literal2' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_1+0', '_1' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '1*_1', '_1' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_1*1', '_1' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_1+_1', '2*_1' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_1-_1', '0' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_1/_1', '1' ) );
            
            // Rate = (pow((EndValue / BeginValue), (1 / (EndYear - BeginYear)))-1) * 100 

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'exp(_Literal1) * exp(_Literal2 )', 'exp( _Literal1 + _Literal2 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'exp( 0 )', '1' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'pow(_Literal1,_1) * pow(_Literal2,_1)', 'pow(_Literal1 * _Literal2,_1)' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'pow( _1, 0 )', '1' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'pow( _1, 1 )', '_1' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'pow( _1, -1 )', '1/_1' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'pow( pow( _1, _Literal1 ), _Literal2 )', 'pow( _1, _Literal1 * _Literal2 )' ) );

//          addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'pow( _Literal1, _1 )', 'ln(_1) / ln(_Literal1)' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_literal1 = pow( _Literal2, _1 )', '_1 = ln(_literal1) / ln(_Literal2)' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'pow( _Literal2, _1 ) = _literal1 ', '_1 = ln(_literal1) / ln(_Literal2)' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'pow( _1, _Literal2 ) = _literal1 ', 'pow( _literal1, 1 / _Literal2 ) = _1' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'pow( 1, _1 )', '1' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_1 * _1 = _literal', '_1 = sqrt( _literal )' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'sqrt( _literal * _1 )', 'sqrt( _literal ) * sqrt( _1 )' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'ln( _Literal1 * _2 )', 'ln( _Literal1 ) + ln( _2 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'ln( _1 * _Literal2 )', 'ln( _Literal2 ) + ln( _1 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'log2( _Literal1 * _2 )', 'log2( _Literal1 ) + log2( _2 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'log2( _1 * _Literal2 )', 'log2( _Literal2 ) + log2( _1 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'log10( _Literal1 * _2 )', 'log10( _Literal1 ) + log10( _2 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'log10( _1 * _Literal2 )', 'log10( _Literal2 ) + log10( _1 )' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'ln( _Literal1 / _2 )', 'ln( _Literal1 ) - ln( _2 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'ln( _1 / _Literal2 )', 'ln( _Literal2 ) - ln( _1 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'log2( _Literal1 / _2 )', 'log2( _Literal1 ) - log2( _2 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'log2( _1 / _Literal2 )', 'log2( _Literal2 ) - log2( _1 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'log10( _Literal1 / _2 )', 'log10( _Literal1 ) - log10( _2 )' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'log10( _1 / _Literal2 )', 'log10( _Literal2 ) - log10( _1 )' ) );
            
        
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1 = _NonLiteral + _Literal2', '_Literal1 - _Literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1 = _NonLiteral * _Literal2', '_Literal1 / _Literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1 = _NonLiteral / _Literal2', '_Literal1 * _Literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1 =_NonLiteral - _Literal2',  '_Literal1 + _Literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_NonLiteral + _Literal2 = _Literal1 ', '_Literal1 - _Literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_NonLiteral * _Literal2 = _Literal1 ', '_Literal1 / _Literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_NonLiteral / _Literal2 = _Literal1 ', '_Literal1 * _Literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_NonLiteral - _Literal2 = _Literal1',  '_Literal1 + _Literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_NonLiteral - _Literal2 = _Literal1 ', '_Literal1 + _Literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal2 - _NonLiteral = _Literal1 ', '_Literal2 - _Literal1 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1 = sin( _NonLiteral )', 'asin( _Literal1 ) = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1 = cos( _NonLiteral )', 'acos( _Literal1 ) = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1 = tan( _NonLiteral )', 'atan( _Literal1 ) = _NonLiteral' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1 = ln( _1 )', 'exp( _Literal1 ) = _1' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( 'ln( _1 ) = _Literal1', 'exp( _Literal1 ) = _1' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1 = _NonLiteral', '_NonLiteral = _Literal1' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '( _Literal1 / _2 ) = _Literal2', '_Literal1 / _Literal2 = _2 ' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal*_NonLiteral', '_NonLiteral*_Literal' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal+_NonLiteral', '_NonLiteral+_Literal' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1+(_Literal2+_NonLiteral)', '_NonLiteral+(_Literal1+_Literal2)' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_Literal1+(_Literal2+_1)', '_1+(_Literal1+_Literal2)' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '(_1*_2)+(_3*_2)', '(_1+_3)*_2' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '(_2*_1)+(_2*_3)', '(_1+_3)*_2' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '(_2*_1)+(_3*_2)', '(_1+_3)*_2' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '(_1*_2)+(_2*_3)', '(_1+_3)*_2' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '(_Literal * _1 ) / _Literal', '_1' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '(_Literal1 * _1 ) / _Literal2', '(_Literal1 * _Literal2 ) / _1' ) );
            
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '(_1+_2)+_3', '_1+(_2+_3)' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '(_1*_2)*_3', '_1*(_2*_3)' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_1+(_1+_2)', '(2*_1)+_2' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_1+_2*_1', '(1+_2)*_1' ) );

            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_literal1 * _NonLiteral = _literal2', '_literal2 / _literal1 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_literal1 + _NonLiteral = _literal2', '_literal2 - _literal1 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_literal1 - _NonLiteral = _literal2', '_literal1 - _literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
            addRule( new TARuleFromString( '_literal1 / _NonLiteral = _literal2', '_literal1 * _literal2 = _NonLiteral' ) );
```

**Make rules first-class expressions**

An interesting point: Since the above rules are special expression, which get correctly evaluate by the expression parser, users can even add new rules and thus enhance the application's rewrite capabilities.

**Parsing expressions (or more general: languages)**

For **Cocoa/OBjC applications**, [Dave DeLong's DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) is a perfect candidate to syntactically analyse mathematical expressions.

For other languages, our old friends [Lex & Yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) or the newer [GNU Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) might be of help.

Far younger and with an [enourmous set of ready to use syntax-files](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4), [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is a modern parser generator based on Java. Besides purely command-line use, [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html) provides a **GUI frontend**  to construct and debug ANTLR based parsers. ANTLR generates grammars for [various host language](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets), like [JAVA, C, Python, PHP or C#](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets). The ActionScript runtime is currently [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480598/problems-building-antlr-v3-3-from-source-antlr3-maven-archetype-missing/6481934#comment-7627243).

In case you'd like to **learn how to parse expressions** (or languages in general) from the bottom-up, I'd propose this [free book's text from Niklaus Wirth](http://www.ethoberon.ethz.ch/WirthPubl/CBEAll.pdf) (or the [german book edition](http://amzn.to/q8rJTF)), the famous inventor of Pascal and Modula-2.

Comment: +1 this is REALLY fascinating and is by far the most promising approach.

Comment: A lot of the rules you've provided are unnecessary, since I don't deal with the `=` operator, but this is giving me lots of ideas.  I'll mark this as correct unless something better arises.

Comment: True! I simply copied all the Flex code. BTW: My solution aims to solve equation systems. User set certain symbols to values and the app compute all remaining ones or proves the system as inconsistent.

Comment: Or, you can just get an engine that contains a term rewriting system and use it.  See http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html

Comment: Any real solution cannot simply unconditionally apply rules over and over. What about sin(x)*sqrt(1+cos(x)^2/(sin(x)^2)) ? Your rules are fine at factoring things out of a square root (eg, they will turn sqrt(9*2) into 3*sqrt(2)), but they will never distribute it back in, which is required here: sqrt(sin(x)^2+cos(x)^2) -> sqrt(1) -> 1. A good solution must be able to go both directions and determine which paths of simplification are the most promising with an AI-style search tree.

Answer (score 12):

This task can become quite complicated (besides the simplest transformation). Essentially this is what [algebra software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) does all the time.

You can find a readable introduction how this is done (rule-based evaluation) e.g. for [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html).

Comment: Definitely, one would use CAS software to simplify terms. But in case one needs to implement term rewriting into an application, a standard CAS isn't the way to go, since most aren't embeddable.

Answer (score 10):

You're wanting to build a CAS (compute algebra system) and the topic is so wide that there is an entire field of study dedicated to it. Which means there are a few [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122042328) that will probably answer your question better than SO.

I know some systems build trees that reduce constants first and then put the tree into a normalized form and then use a [large database of proven/known formulas](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/16/) to transform the problem into some other form.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to "brute force" such trees.

You will have to formulate a couple of rules that describe possible simplifications. Then you habe to walk through the tree and search for applicable rules. Since some simplifications might lead to simpler results than others you will have to do a similar thing that you do for finding the shortest route on a subway plan: try out all possibilities and sort the results by some quality criteria.

Since the number of such scenarios is finite you might be able to discover the simplification rules automatically by trying out all combinations of operators and variables and again have a genetic algorithm that verifies that the rule has not been found before and that it actually simplifies the input.

Multiplications can be represented as additions, so one rule might be that a - a cancels itself out:  2a-a = a+a-a

Another rule would be to first multiply out all divisions because those are fractions. Example:

1/2 + 3/4
Discover all the divisions and then multiply each fraction with the divisor on both sides of all other fractions

4/8 + 6/8
Then all elements have the same divisor and so can the unified to
(4+6)/8 = 10/8

Finally you find the highest common divisor between top and bottom
5/4

Applied to your tree the strategy would be to work from the bottom leaves upwards simplifying each multiplication first by converting it to additions. Then simplifying each addition like the fractions

All the while you would check agains your shortcut rules to discover such simplifcations. To know that a rule applies you probably have to either try out all permutations of a subtree. E.g. The a-a rule would also apply for -a+a. There might be a a+b-a.

Just some thoughts, hope that gives you some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't in general do this because, although they are the same mathematically, the may not be the same in computer arithmetic.  For instance, -MAX_INT is undefined, so --%a =/= %a.  Similarly for floats, you have to deal with NaN and Inf appropriately.

Comment: Assuming 2's complement, -MAX_INT is MIN_INT+1 but -MIN_INT is MIN_INT. So yes, --a = a, but not always in a nice way (ie there is an a such that -a=a even though a!=0)

Answer (score 0):

My naive approach would be to have some sort of data structure with inverses of each function (i.e. `divide` and `multiply`). You would obviously need further logic to make sure they are actually inverse since multiplying by 3 and then dividing by 4 is not actually an inverse.

Although this is primitive, I think it's a decent first pass at the problem and would solve a lot of the cases you noted in your question.

I do look forward to seeing your full solution and staring in awe at is mathematical brilliance :)