# Simplify algebraic expression

Tags: c#, math, tree, algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strategies for simplifying math expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540227/strategies-for-simplifying-math-expressions)

I have a mathematical expression parser which builds a tree to represent the expression. Say ,for example, I input `2+y+3+y`, the internal representation of this would be:

[image]

Now, we, as humans, can immediately see that `2+y+3+y = 2y + 5`. The tricky part for the computer that I see, is that if I would be standing on the left `+`, I would have no idea that I have another addition to the right in the other branch - this doesn't matter when evaluating but when simplifying i don't see how this can be done nicely.

This is how the classes fit together:
[image]

I have tried to google this, but have found nothing that could help me here. Just some general waypoint, or an url or something at all would be appreciated

**EDIT:** Note that for the example i have only included addition. The parser supports expressions like : 1+2*(3^4-4/5*(1+2))

Comment: Addition is transitive. From the root +, can it not see that both children are also addition: meaning it can rearrange the constants and variables as it sees fit?

Comment: Could you make `+` have more than 2 children? I believe symbolic math languages like Mathematica would store your example as a list `[2,y,3,y]` with a head of `Plus`, which would then get simplified automatically using some rules.

Comment: Is that really how your parse tree gets built?  I bet it isn't.

Comment: @Novak you're probably right. I would guess the left branch just consists of the constant 2.

Comment: @ColinD I have many more operators and functions than just addition. It wouldn't fit in the width of SO.

Comment: Since a+b+c = c+b+a why not let addition have a list of SymbolicExpression's. That's one step. But then you have that 2y is a multiplication of a constant 2 and a variable y. And 2y+3y = 5y might be somewhat harder...

Comment: I think the hardest part of your problem then is with the parts you don't show, i.e. precedence and scope (grouping with parentheses), and determining what CAN be combined that correctly respects those. Wouldn't an answer helpful to you need to consider that?

Comment: Explicit parentheses output is done by SymbolicExpression having a int Priority-getter, which the childs override. + having a lower priority than * for example. So if addition is a child of multiplication the addition gets a parenthesis

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540227/strategies-for-simplifying-math-expressions?

Comment: I just found something called _prefix notation_. Seems promising

Comment: @ie. that looks horrible. There must be a better way.

Comment: Please ignore my previous answer and accept my apology for dropping such a brain-fart on your question.

Comment: @ErikTJ that looks perfect! just like the musik for the eyes ;)

Comment: Yep, that ruleset looks exactly what you'll want.

Comment: I guess I'm also uncertain as to why you want to do this:  Is it intended to be a compiler optimization to get the compiled code to run faster?  Is it part of a symbolic package meant to display information to humans?  Something else>

Comment: @Novak No, it's just for fun.

Comment: Object oriented programming is the wrong tool for the job here. Symbolic computations are much more easily solved using algebraic data types (sums and products) and pattern matching. Try using a language like Standard ML, OCaml, Haskell, F#, Mathematica or even Scala.

Answer (score 0):

Since the set of expressions that can be expressed with your class structure is quite limited, you can simply count how often each variable occurs and sum all the constants.

```
var nodes = tree.Flatten();

var variables = nodes
    .OfType<Variable>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => new Multiplication(
        new Variable(g.Key), new Constant(g.Count())));

var constants = nodes
    .OfType<Constant>()
    .Sum(x => x.Value);

var result = new Addition(
    variables.Aggregate((x, y) => new Addition(x, y)), 
    new Constant(constants));
```

Comment: I included a limited number of operators and functions. I have + - * / log pow exp ( ).

Comment: @ErikTJ: But you asked only about addition. A generic solution for arbitrary algebraic expression is something you're likely to find in CS text books; IMO it's too much to ask for here.