# Optimizing/reducing pure functions with same in/out types to combine them in a simpler pure function?

Tags: function, optimization, design-patterns

Disclaimer: I have almost no mathematics notions, so this question could be very basic for some of you.

I'm searching for the name of a concept which consists in combining pure functions together (say, functions with the same input and output types and number of parameters) to make them simpler.

Suppose I have these 3 methods with the same signature:

```
addOne(param: number): number {
   return param + 1;
}

addTwo(param: number): number {
    return param + 2;
}

multiplyByThree(param: number): number  {
    return param * 3;
}
```

Now I know that I'll always use these functions in the same order and same param.

Ex: I will process a sound or an image.

I want to avoid uselessly applying coefficient or offsets that could be computed together (optimization/regression).

Let's say I have this imaginary library with a method called `computeOptimizedFunction` that applies this concept to my functions. It takes any number of functions with the same signature as input.

```
var optimized = computeOptimizedFunction(addOne, addTwo, multiplyByThree);
```

Actually equals to:

```
var optimized = (param: number) => 3 * (param + 3);
```

Anyone here has an idea of how this concept or pattern is called, if it exists?

Comment: This is not a simple topic, if it were that simple all compilers would be doing it. Restricted to math expressions, you could try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540227/strategies-for-simplifying-math-expressions

Comment: Indeed, at the end, I realize that there is a requirement to combine all expressions and to follow operator/operation priorities. And if there are conditions inside functions, I lose optimization opportunities. At the strict minimum, I want to reduce at least the number of function entry points. I'll read that linked question throughfully, thanks! I feel like I'll need a code analyzer to separate code in blocks before combining and optimizing functions. Funny side-project, isn't it!

Comment: Many compilers inline functions to avoid the calls, feel free to play around with it but these things are usually left for the compiler